# How can i write mysql query for two relational table with count() function for showing all data?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `category`

```
category_id    category_name
 1               category-1
 2               category-2
 3               category-3
 4               category-4
 5               category-5
```

**Primary key** :category_id

Table  `product`

```
product_id   product_name   ref_category_id  product_status

1             xxxx              1                Available
2             xxxx              2                Not Available
3            xxxxx             3                 Available
4            xxxxx             1                 Available
5            xxxxx             1                 Not Available
```

**Primary key** : product_id
**Foreign key** : ref_category_id references category(category_id)

I want to write a single sql query for showing below's result:

```
Category_name   total_available_products_for_this_category

category-1                          2
category-2                          0
category-3                          1
category-4                          0
category-5                          0
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so in Mysql,by using expression in `sum()` then sum will sum up the boolean values (0/1) returned by expression and you can have your count on basis your conditions

```
select c.* ,coalesce(sum(p.product_status = 'Available'),0)
from category c
left join product p on(p.ref_category_id = c.category_id )
group by c.category_id
```

use `coalesce()` to show 0 instead of NULL

### [**`Fiddle Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7b68/2)

**Edit from comments**

If you use count(*),this will count all the associations (products) of each category group regardless of status value ,if you still want to stick with count then you have to use `CASE` statement in it like `count(case when p.product_status = 'Available' then 1 end)` so when product has `product_status` of `Available` then count it other wise neglect count so this is what i have for i have use sum with expression without `CASE` statement ,

```
select c.* ,
count(case when p.product_status = 'Available' then 1 end)
from category c
left join product p on(p.ref_category_id = c.category_id )
group by c.category_id
```

### [`Count Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7b68/4)

**Edit 2**

The same result can be achieved bu using `count(distinct p.product_id)` to only count distinct products for each category,now i am not using any condition in in sum function and not using `CASE` statement in count also using simply `count(distinct p.product_id)`,but i have not directly join product table instead i have used a subquery to get all products from product table where `product_status = 'Available'` so the subquery will return only products that are available and then i have joined this resultset of subquery with category table to get the count

```
select c.* ,
count(distinct p.product_id)
from category c
left join
( select * from 
product where product_status = 'Available'
) p
on(p.ref_category_id = c.category_id )
group by c.category_id
```

Hope it gives you some  more clear idea to use count

### [`Count Demo 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7b68/7)

Comment: Thank you,but what is the problem with count function?If i put count function then it is counting all.Can you give me some nice explanation for it then it will be nice for me. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much that you could understand me very well.I got my answer.But i want to know more about this problem for count() function without using condition.When you will find some good answer please inform me.In Sha Allah we will get perfect answer.

Comment: @user3909926 InShaAllah i will let you know ,this is my last try to give you idea to still use it with count see my last edit in answer